# Genuine Student Rule for Tier 4 Applications

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa, uk-visa, students

Does it hurt a Tier 4 applicant's credibility if their spouse is already a UK resident?

Comment: On what basis is your spouse in the UK? Work? Study?

Answer (score 1):

No, not exactly. But you must be a genuine student, coming to the UK for the purposes of study, and able to qualify on these grounds alone (as if you weren't married to a UK resident). If you are not a genuine student, and are only coming to join your spouse by another means, the Home Office is quite savy to this, and then your application will get the extra scrutiny it deserves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My husband is on DLR but he qualifies now for an ILR based on long residence. I truly do want to go study AND be with him, the course reflects academic progression to my previous study. Additionally, I am co-funding my studies via an educational loan scheme from a local bank. I don't even want to live in the U.K. After my course ends. We're going to move out as he will have already be naturalized at the end of the period, hopefully.

Comment: DLR? Could be a while before he is naturalized depending on if there were any periods of overstay before he was granted DLR. And the spirit of the process of ILR > UK Citizenship is that you will make the UK your home and base of life, not just get the passport and leave.

Comment: In support of @ouflak's comment, see [Become a British citizen](https://www.gov.uk/becoming-a-british-citizen). One of the conditions listed is "you’ll continue to live in the UK".